# Android: Pull out emoji keyboard on button press

Tags: android

I know that you can specify a short message input type in order to turn the enter key of the keyboard into an emoji button and pressing it will show up the emoji list but what i want to do is open up the emoji list programatically from a button. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

There is no functionality to add tabs to any generic keyboard. Certain keyboards may support it, but it isn't a common feature. You could write your own fully custom keyboard, but that's a lot of work and will piss off many users.

Also, I'm not sure what you mean about by like in hangouts. I use hangouts- it doesn't do anything odd with my keyboard. It stays as Swype, there's no special emoji tab. It may be a feature of your favorite keyboard based on the input type (I assume both use input type textShortMessage). But it isn't a generic feature.

**See Link** [Android Keyboard with Emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167428/android-keyboard-with-emoji?rq=1)

Thanks and enjoy...