# Cordova Ionic: Enable android emoji soft keyboard

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, ionic-framework

With Cordova Ionic Android you can call for the Search keyboard with: `<input type="search">`:

[image]

I'm trying to access the Emoji keyboard with: `<input type="textShortMessage">`

[image]

But it isn't working.

`textShortMessage` is based off this SO question: [Android Keyboard with Emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167428/android-keyboard-with-emoji) which is for direct Android development.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: nope, no solution yet

Comment: android 4.1 and above versions show emojis when we long press enter key. but those emojis don't seem to be cool

Comment: @alyx found solution?

Comment: `<input type="textShortMessage">` works. I just checked it and got the complete set of emojis.

Tested in HTC 802 Android version 5.0.2

Comment: you may to create custom emoji keybord https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker

Comment: You can try on the following link for the same if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413387/how-to-open-the-emoji-soft-keyboard-in-hybrid-app