# How to open the Emoji soft keyboard in hybrid app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, reactjs, ionic-framework

How can I open the Emoji soft keyboard in a Hybrid app?

e.g. using Cordova/Ionic/Angular/React

Comment: This is just a very generic, and opinion based question.. should it be here?

Comment: Thinking about it, `ionic = cordova + angular`, so the question is about `ionic`/`react-native`, it doesn't seem too much generic to me given that any solution could probably be adapted to work with both. How can an answer be debatable?

Comment: It's hardly a question about how to debug or solve a programming question is it. In fact, you've only 'gotten around' the rule of having to use `code` in your question, by using them as labels. I just know that if I or others were to ask a similar question of how to do something, it would be downvoted and closed pretty quickly.

Comment: I've edited the question, does `How to open the Emoji soft keyboard` seems cleaner and better highlights the problem?

I used `code` for readability and this rule you mention doesn't seem to [exist](http://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Comment: For the record, React Native is not a hybrid framework, so the answers for Ionic / RN will be fundamentally different, I'm assuming.

Comment: Ok, I've removed RN and added react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw this library,take a look at this "https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker"

Comment: Oh, I've not seen the link in `angular-emoji-popup` pointing to this. This is nice!