# Emoji application with keyboard integration

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ionic-framework, emoji

I need to make a mobile application, if it can be Ionic best, if not possible as native.
In the application I need to buy some emoji can be done for me, and then they can be integrated into the keyboard so that you can send by Whatsapp or any messaging application.
Someone can give me help, links, code.
I'm totally lost and not know where to start.
Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884220/cordova-ionic-enable-android-emoji-soft-keyboard

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167428/android-keyboard-with-emoji

Comment: above links will help you for sure..

Comment: did you test even? it should work without change any thing in <input type="text"/>