# How to create the custom keyboard with emoji

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I have done the custom keyboard but i have no idea for add the emoji in custom keyboard.

I have some link for emoji keyboard

https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

https://github.com/mobindustry/emojikeyboard

https://github.com/klinker24/Android-SlidingEmojiKeyboard

But i don't know how to used that in custom keyboard like below images.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbCLQ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dheCa.png

So Please help me
Thank you.

Comment: Ok see [Android Keyboard with Emoji](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167428/android-keyboard-with-emoji) post

Comment: see this link you got class which is written all class how to used its example  https://github.com/mobindustry/emojikeyboard/tree/master/app/src/main/java/net/mobindustry/emoji_keyboard

Comment: @Vishal Thakkar but how to show when click on emoji key of custom keyboard like google keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [library](https://github.com/hani-momanii/SuperNova-Emoji) to open up custom keyboard for `emoji` and works fine for me.
This also contains sample to illustrate.

Via Gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/hani-momanii/maven"}
}
  compile 'hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library:supernova-emoji-library:0.0.2'
```

Comment: how to open the emoji keyboard when i click on emoji key of the custom keyboard?

Comment: Just check the sample of library that will clear it in better ways. Anyways there is EmojIconActions class in library to handle keyboard events.

Comment: I already add that code when click on emoji key at that time not open the emoji keyboard